# Extract all characters before Parenthesis R

Tags: r, regex, data-manipulation, strsplit

I would imagine there is a simple regex solution for this - I want to extract everything that appears before the first left "(" parenthesis in the Name column.

My current code returns this:

```
df$New_Name <- strsplit(df$Name, '[()]')[[1]][[1]]

Name          New_Name 
1abc (55x50)  1abc
1abc (50x40)  1abc
2def (20x15)  1abc
2def (25x12)  1abc
3ghi (30x5)   1abc
3ghi (30x10)  1abc
```

The code I am running works only for the first instance. For 2def, 3ghi etc it is not returning the correct string.

Desired Output:

```
Name          New_Name 
1abc (55x50)  1abc
1abc (50x40)  1abc
2def (20x15)  2def
2def (25x12)  2def
3ghi (30x5)   3ghi
3ghi (30x10)  3ghi
```

Answer (score 4):

`strsplit` returns a `list`.  By extracting the first element `[[1]]`, it is only returning the contents of the first `list` element.  Then, whatever values are extracted i.e. first element of first list element `[[1]][[1]]`, it is just a single value and by assignment, this gets recycled

```
df$New_Name <- sapply(strsplit(df$Name, '\\s*[()]'), `[`, 1)
```

In the above code, instead of doing the extraction of first element, loop over the `list` with `sapply`, and extract the first element

---

Another option is `trimws` by specifying the regex in `whitespace` as zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by the `(` and other characters (`.*`)

```
df$New_Name <- trimws(df$Name, whitespace = "\\s*\\(.*")
```

Or may use `sub`

```
df$New_Name <- sub("\\s*\\(.*", "", df$Name)
```

-output

```
df
          Name New_Name
1 1abc (55x50)     1abc
2 1abc (50x40)     1abc
3 2def (20x15)     2def
4 2def (25x12)     2def
5  3ghi (30x5)     3ghi
6 3ghi (30x10)     3ghi
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("1abc (55x50)", "1abc (50x40)", "2def (20x15)", 
"2def (25x12)", "3ghi (30x5)", "3ghi (30x10)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```